# How to interact with an Actor, by setting a pointer at OnComponentBeginOverlap to the player actor?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

My aim is it to access a function of the "door actor object" from the code of my "player character actor object", for instance to open or close the door.

Would be great if someone could fix my attempt or know a similar or better solution.

This is code from the "door":

```
#include "DefaultDoorRotator.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.h"

void ADefaultDoorRotator::OnOverlapBegin(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlapComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweepm, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (player_controled_door)
    {
        if (OtherActor != nullptr)
        {
            if ((OtherActor->GetClass()->GetDefaultObject<AFPSCharacter>()!=0))
            {
                OtherActor->GetClass()->GetDefaultObject<AFPSCharacter>()->set_interaction_object(ActionComponent);
                GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Registered Door on Player!"));
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Here from the player:

```
#include "FPSCharacter.h"
#include "DefaultDoorRotator.h"

USceneComponent* object_for_interaction;

    UFUNCTION()
    void set_interaction_object(USceneComponent* obj)
    {
        if (obj != 0)
        {
            object_for_interaction = obj;
        }

    }

void AFPSCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("CharacterInteract", IE_Pressed, this, &AFPSCharacter::Interaction_start);
}

void AFPSCharacter::Interaction_start()
{
    want_to_interact = true;
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Want to interact!"));
    if (object_for_interaction != 0)
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Begin to interact!"));
        object_for_interaction->GetClass()->GetDefaultObject<ADefaultDoorRotator>()->ToggleDoor();

    }


}
```

When this would work, the function of the door actor object should run.

Comment: So what's the issue currently?

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of strange example because you can achieve the same behavior by just checking the overlapping actors for any doors when the player character presses the bound key. But, I'm assuming you want to know how to generally call functions on other actors of specific types when the UE4 api is handing you AActor pointers.

UE4 has a templated Cast function that returns null if the cast fails. That's typically what you want to use to get what you're trying to do here. For example,

```
if (OtherActor != nullptr)
{
    if ((OtherActor->GetClass()->GetDefaultObject<AFPSCharacter>()!=0))
    {
        OtherActor->GetClass()->GetDefaultObject<AFPSCharacter>()->set_interaction_object(ActionComponent);
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Registered Door on Player!"));
    }
}
```

becomes

```
AFPSCharacter* character = Cast<AFPSCharacter>(OtherActor);
if (character)
{
    character->set_interaction_object(ActionComponent);
}
```